# How to create Folder in Remote Location

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, webrequest, create-directory

Right now I have this code which creates a folder in the specified path..

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        albname = txtName.Text.ToString();
        try
        {
            string targetPath = Server.MapPath("..//Images//Albums//" + albname); 
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {

                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                id = id + 1;
                con.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand("insert into album values(" + id + ",'" + albname + "')", con);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Album Successfully added');", true);
                con.Close();
                txtName.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "msgbox", "alert('Album Name Already Exists!Please enter a different Name');", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ne)
        {
            error.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = ne.ToString();

        }

    }
```

This works well and fine for me now.. It creates a folder in specified path..
Now I am running this website in Localhost.. **now when I host website in any server does the above code work?? or do is there any different way to create a folder when my website is Live on Internet**.. Hope I will get any beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

It should work on your server also, as long as you have permissions to create a folder in the specified directory.
Why don't you try it and see? If you get an error, make sure to post the full error message.

Comment: @ricovox... Right now am running it in localhost.. How to test it in server? I have no idea about it as I am developing the first website...

Comment: How to upload your site is another whole question by itself. This will depend a lot on the server you are uploading to. First, you will have to make sure that the server supports ASP.NET. If you are uploading to a shared hosting site that is run on Linux/Apache, then it probably will NOT run ASP.NET. Look for a host that specifically states it supports ASP.NET, and then make sure the version is the same or better that the one you're developing in. (e.g. .Net 3.5, 4, 4.5 etc)

Comment: Once you have your hosting service, they will probably have information on how and where to upload your files. You can use the visual studio IDE to compile and deploy your website to a local folder and then upload all files in that folder to your hosting provider, probably using FTP. You can even have Visual Studio deploy the files to your server directly.

Comment: You should just search for "how to deploy asp.net website" and include the version of the IDE and/or and framework you are interested in.  Like "how to deploy asp.net website VS 2012 express"
Here is a link to more about deployment using VS 2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx

Comment: Wow... Thanks for such a beautiful explaination... Superb... definitely will go through it... :) Thank u... :)